# Can't Get Any LaTeX Editor To Run

Tags: errors, compiling, texstudio, texworks

I just build a desktop and seem to be having issues getting LaTeX to run.

**Important Information:**

- Windows 7 (64-bit)
- Asus Radeon R9 290
- All LaTeX-related software is saved on the non-OS drive
- Several different editors have been installed and tested (MikTex, LyX, TeXstudio, and TeXworks), all of  seem to be unable to compile/build anything - several were re-installed as a test
- No log file seems to be created

As test code I've been using a basic example copied from the internet, in case it's a package issue, and a cover letter I wrote, as I can guarantee it works (though it does require some packages). Any ideas on what could be the issue here? Thanks for the help!

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Basic Test Code:**

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
%   options include 12pt or 11pt or 10pt
%   classes include article, report, book, letter, thesis

\title{This is the title}
\author{Author One \\ Author Two}
\date{29 February 2004}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is the content of this document.

This is the 2nd paragraph.
Here is an inline formula:
$   V = \frac{4 \pi r^3}{3}  $.
And appearing immediately below
is a displayed formula:
$$  V = \frac{4 \pi r^3}{3}  $$
\end{document}
```

**Cover Letter Test (with personal information removed):**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Short Stylish Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (28/5/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Stefano (http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/63)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% IMPORTANT: THIS TEMPLATE NEEDS TO BE COMPILED WITH XeLaTeX
%
% The two fonts used in this template: Adobe Garamond Pro and Gill Sans
% do not come with Windows by default. You will need to download them in
% order to get an output as in the preview PDF. Otherwise, change those 
% fonts to fonts that do come with Windows or comment out the lines to use 
% the default font.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{scrlttr2}

%\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{marvosym} % Allows the use of symbols
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Required to compile in Windows
\usepackage{graphicx}


\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont {Adobe Garamond Pro} % Main document font
\setsansfont {Cambria} % Used in the from address line above the to address

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont} % Sets the font size and leading
\def\second{{\raise.5ex\hbox{\small nd}}}
\makeatletter
\@setplength{refvpos}{8cm}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  PERSONAL INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\setkomavar{fromname}{Name} % Your name
%\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address} % Your address
%\setkomavar{fromphone}{(555) 555-5555} % Your phone number
%\setkomavar{fromemail}{myemail@gmail.com} % Your email address
%\setkomavar{place}{} % City written before the date, put your city here if you want this
\setkomavar{signature}{My Name} % Your name as you want it to appear in the signature
%\setkomavar{date}{\flushleft\vspace{-\baselineskip}\today\par}
\setkomavar{date}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\newkomavar{phone}
\newkomavar{email}
\setkomavar{phone}{(555) 555-5555}
\setkomavar{email}{myemail@gmail.com}

% These are not used in this document, uncomment if you would like to use them and refer to them as \usekomavar{name}
%\setkomavar{fromfax}{+1 (1)23 456789} % Your fax number
%\setkomavar{fromurl}{http://www.johnsmith.com} % Your personal website
%\setkomavar{frombank}{Postbank 9307157}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  HEADER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firsthead{
\centering
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\scshape Name}\\[5mm]
\fontsize{21}{21}\selectfont\scshape My Title \\ My Institution } % Your current job title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  FOOTER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\firstfoot{
%\centering
%\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\scshape
%{
%\renewcommand{\\}{\ {\large\textperiodcentered}\ }
%\usekomavar{fromaddress}
%}\\
%{\Large\Letter} \usekomavar{fromemail} \ {Large\Telefon} \usekomavar{fromphone} % If you want your fax number or website URL showing, add it here; you may need to play around with spacing
%}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% COVER LETTER CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{letter}{ % Address of the company you are applying to
\today \par \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
Biotech Company \\
123 Street Street \\
Washington, CA 12345 
}

%\setkomavar{subject}{Cover Letter} % This is the bold text saying 'Cover Letter', remove it if you don't like it

\opening{Dear Mr. Thompson:\\}

\begin{sloppypar}
My name is...

Thank you for your time and consideration. I am looking forward to a further discussion of this job position. \\

\end{sloppypar}

Sincerely, \\
%\includegraphics[width=6cm]{Signature.png}

\usekomavar{signature}\\ 
\usekomavar{phone}\\
\usekomavar{email}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

**Confirmation of Hard Drive Recognition:**
[image]

Comment: "All LaTeX-related software is saved on the non-OS drive" -- which drive, and which TeX distribution?

Comment: Your basic text code works fine. Can you add the log file to see what's wrong?

Comment: Mico:

The non-OS drive is the "F" storage drive. It's a mechanical hard drive, whereas the OS is placed on a SSD. The disributions I've tried so far are:

MikTex
LyX
TeXstudio
TeXworks

Pablos:

No log file is created. For example, in TeXworks the compile button yields only this output 
"This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)"

Comment: If `F` is known to the system, it should be OK.

Comment: Open a Console (cmd.exe, or with shift plus right click -> open console) and type in `pdflatex` and press `Enter`. What happens?

Comment: Did you check the paths?

Comment: "C:\Users\Peter\pdflatex" 
"This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.51.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)" Does that mean LaTeX some how got installed on the wrong hard drive?

Comment: Pablos: 

Not sure how to do that, though that sounds like something I need to do.

Comment: Do note that MiKTeX is a distribution (provides `pdflatex`, packages etc.) while the others are all just editors. (Well, LyX isn't exactly an editor but for these purposes, it is the same thing.)

Comment: Please try to install in c drive. TexWorks editor can be downloaded from CTAN. Others like Texmaker, LyX, Kile etc can be downloaded and installed. Did you set MikTeX path in system's environment variables?

Comment: If pdflatex works in the console the paths should be set correctly

Comment: first try to run the code directly from TeXworks instead of using any front editor. It might be possible that front editors are not configured with LaTex.

Comment: I re-installed TeXworks on to the C drive. I still have the same issue where hitting the compile button only yields this text: "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)". When I exit out of the whole thing is informs me that a typesetting process is still running, though nothing is actually happening - it's like the the entire LaTeX language is stuck in some endless loop on this machine exclusively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I had an old hard drive with a version of LaTeX installed on it, so when the compiler ran it was calling packages from the old copy- resulting in an endless loop of sorts. Deleting any and all LaTeX files from the hard drive, plus a clear install on the new one, resulted in all the problems being solved. In hindsight I should have just done that right away, but I didn't think LaTeX would do a global search for packages rather than just look in the associated local folder.